# CakePHP allow forward slash as named parameter value

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakePHP and got stuck in a situation. I want to pass a named parameter to my action that contains forward slashes. For example

http://www.test.com/claim/index/user:rLbu78h2RpVwLTy/bki3pK1NkkXhCCaYfQ/zXDIfZR4=

Basically "rLbu78h2RpVwLTy/bki3pK1NkkXhCCaYfQ/zXDIfZR4=" is one parameter but cake is only recognizing the first part of it until the fist slash.

When printing the named params array I get:

```
Array
(
    [user] => rLbu78h2RpVwLTy
)
```

How can I escape the forward slash and allow cake to accept it as part of the named parameter?

Thank you

Comment: The key question is: how do you create your url? The PHP code is missing. And why did you not specify your cake version?

Comment: cakephp 2.1.1 and URL is an mcrypt of an email address.

Comment: You still did not post any of your PHP code there. Note that CakePHP usually automatically encodes the url if you do it properly. It should also be noted that in most cases its better to use query strings instead of named params (which will be deprecated in future versions, anway!).

Comment: @AD7six thank you very much that was the answer I was looking for :) ... worked like a charm. If you want to put it as an answer I will mark it as correct. Thanks again.

Comment: I second @mark comment. I think he wrote a complete post on his blog to justify this... [read here](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/05/04/passed-named-or-query-string-params/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Don't use named-parameters

While you *can* use named parameters (`/foo/this-is:a-named-parameter/`), it's best to stick to normal url positional/path arguments and/or `GET` arguments. Over time it has proven not to be a great solution to pass around information using named parameters.

### Use a trailing star route

If you modify the format of the url you're using to be e.g.:

```
/claim/index/<user token>
```

Then you can use a [trailing star route](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#connecting-routes) to captuer everythiing that occurs after `/index/` in a single variable:

```
Router::connect(
    '/claim/index/**',
    array('controller' => 'claims', 'action' => 'index')
);
```

In this way it doesn't matter what comes after `/index/` you'll receive it in your index action:

```
// Request to /index/rLbu78h2RpVwLTy/bki3pK1NkkXhCCaYfQ/zXDIfZR4=

function index($user) {
    // $user === 'rLbu78h2RpVwLTy/bki3pK1NkkXhCCaYfQ/zXDIfZR4='
}
```

Comment: Won't this be a PITA in case where multiple params must be passed? How about [Querystring parameters](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#accessing-querystring-parameters)? In fact, in 3.0, support for named parameters is removed and [use of querystring is recommended](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#named-parameters). However there is a solution for [backward compatibility](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#handling-named-parameters-in-urls)

Comment: `and/or GET arguments` is in the answer.