# How to pass a parameter with a forward slash in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I have a controller:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * FundingYears Controller
 *
 */
class FundingYearsController extends AppController {

/**
 * Scaffold
 *
 * @var mixed
 */
    public $scaffold;

}
```

When try to pass a parameter (a primary key) through the URL because it has a '/' in it, it bombs it out:

```
http://localhost/funding_years/view/12%2F13
```

Is there any way to escape this using Routes?

Comment: seen this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15529872/cakephp-allow-forward-slash-as-named-parameter-value

Comment: Use only a-z0-9-_ etc for url parts. You should use query strings for all params that need to be passed via url that are not ascii chars. Especially if they contain chars that are special in urls, like slashes. Those are automatically correctly encoded and decoded. See [details](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/05/04/passed-named-or-query-string-params/). You can also sluggify what you want to use as passed param here - such a slug can be created automatically via behaviors.

Comment: Router::connect('/funding_years/view/**', array('controller' => 'funding_years', 'action' => 'view')); doesn't work just ends up as: http://localhost/funding_years/view/12%2F1312%2F13. Using CakePHP v2.4.5

Comment: What version of Cake are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following sample code :

```
$link1 = array('controller'=>'funding_years','action'=>'view');
$link2  = explode('/','12/13');
$link =array_merge($link1,$link2);
echo $this->Html->url($link);
```